# Firebase : Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite not found

Tags: android, firebase, flutter

I have been experiencing a problem for a few days on my flutter application, when setting up FireBase in my application:

"Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite not found."

I tested several solutions found on forums:

- Clean project - Rebuilt - Invalidate cache on android studio
- Uninstall my application completely from my phone (sufficient storage and active internet connection)
- Added internet and access_network_state permissions in the android manifest before <application ()

I use the latest version of the Firebase package. My googles play services are up to date, and my phone is recent.

Would anyone have had this problem and/or know what to do 
Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Are you dealing with firebase firestore by any chance?

Answer (score -1):

Clearing app cache from device helps in some cases.